# Changing .html() of <option> resets selectedIndex property of <option> from '-1' to '0'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Using jQuery when changing `.html()` of an `<option>` inside a `<select>` (Which I had previously set `selectedIndex` property to `-1`) resets `selectedIndex` property of `<select>` from '`-1`' to '`0`'

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<select id="myselect" class="drpmnu">

   <option id="one" >(01)</option>

   <option id="two" >(02)</option>

   <option id="three" >(03)</option>

</select>
  <script>
    $(".drpmnu").prop('selectedIndex', -1)
    $('#three').html("moo")
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsbin.com/filowe/2/edit?html,output

Comment: The best I can figure is that it is a repaint issue. When you change the text of the option is causes the select to repaint. In the repaint there is an issue where the prop gets reset to the default value.

Comment: `$('#three')[0].text="moo";` doesn't reset the index, but `textContent` does.

Comment: @dandavis, `$('#three')[0].text="moo";` doesn't work in IE (at least in IE11)

Comment: Just **don't use `.html()`** on `<option>` elements! [Those](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-option-element) must contain only `Text`, not arbitrary html. Try using `.text()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This case is mentioned in the [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html):

> On setting, the [`selectedIndex`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-select-selectedindex) attribute must set the *selectedness* of all the option elements in the list of options to false, and then the option element in the list of options whose index is the given new value, if any, must have its *selectedness* set to true and its *dirtiness* set to true.
>
> > **Note:** This can result in no element having a *selectedness* set to true even in the case of the select element having no multiple attribute and a display size of 1.
>
> ...
>
> If nodes are inserted or nodes are removed causing the list of options to gain or lose one or more option elements, or if an option element in the list of options [*asks for a reset*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#ask-for-a-reset), then, if the select element's multiple attribute is absent, the select element's display size is 1, and no option elements in the select element's list of options have their *selectedness* set to true, the user agent must set the *selectedness* of the first option element in the list of options in tree order that is not disabled, if any, to true.

Changing an option via setting its `innerHTML` or `textContent` property triggers this reset (except on Firefox), but the `text` property (which is `<option>` only) does not trigger it (except on IE).

```
// these triggers the <select> element's reset (except on Firefox)
$("#three")[0].innerHTML   = "foo";
$("#three")[0].textContent = "foo";

// this does not trigger the reset (except on IE)
$("#three")[0].text = "foo";
```

Firefox follows the spec more strictly, it only resets the `<select>` if there is a new `<option>`, or there was a removal of one of the `<option>`s. But it fails to execute the reset during setting an `<option>`'s `selected` property to false (but [that should trigger](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-option-selected) the reset too).

In short, all of the current browsers fail to implement the spec completely, so the only cross-platform workaround is to change `selectedIndex` as the last operation on a select (and its descendant elements):

```
$("#three").html("moo");
$(".drpmnu").prop("selectedIndex", -1);
```

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is different across various browsers. I just checked in firefox and it worked without any error. It shown me an empty dropdown and I checked the selected index was -1. The result was not same in Chrome though.

Ideally, -1 is used for select when no option is selected in starting. I am not sure if -1 can be set programmatically across all the browsers.

> Changing option's HTML does not trigger the change event, if it would - the following code will end up running infinite loop.

```
var i = 0;
$(".drpmnu").change(function (e) {
    i++;
    $('#three').html("data" + i);
})
```

Comment: Vijay, I agree. The Chrome Dev Tools didn't list the event either!

Answer (score 1):

At first I've looked into a JQuery [.html()](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=2.0.3&fn=jQuery.fn.html) function, but couldn't find anything that could cause the problem. Then I've tried to [change innerHTML property without jquery](http://jsbin.com/jopisunozi/2/edit?html,output) (this is what I should have done first). It looks OK on Firefox 33.1 and 34.0.5, but resets `selectedIndex` with Chrome 40.0.2214.94, IE 10 and Opera 27.0.1689.66.

I think this proves that @Blake Plumb's comment is correct, for some browsers.

> It is a repaint issue. When you change the text of the option is causes the select to
>   repaint. In the repaint there is an issue where the prop gets reset to
>   the default value.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're setting the HTML contents of `$('#three')` after pre-setting the index. Therefore, if you want to keep the index of `-1`, rearrange your code to load in order.

```
<script>
    $('#three').html("moo");
    $(".drpmnu").prop('selectedIndex', -1);
</script>
```

An onchange event is automatically triggered when an elements value changes. Thus, the reset of the index.

Comment: Despite that this answer solves the problem, it's more interesting why change of option's html affects select's selectedIndex

Comment: If so, shouldn't  `$('#three').trigger('change');` have the same effect as `$('#three').html("moo");` for selecetedIndex?